# Is it possible for non US citizen tourists to get married in Las Vegas?

Tags: legal, eu-citizens, las-vegas, weddings

I see this in many movies but I ask myself if it's true - can I just go to Las Vegas with my girlfriend and get married?

If yes, do I need any documents from my home country (such as to prove that I am not already married and so on)?

Will my home country (Bulgaria) recognize the marriage and are there any fees?

Comment: details at http://www.vegas.com/weddings/las-vegas-wedding-legal-requirements/ and http://govegas.about.com/od/lasvegaswedding/a/lvwedding.htm could probably be combined (By someone with more time than I have today) into an answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is yes, because I know a couple (both from different non-US countries) who did that. No idea about what formalities are needed or whether every country will recognize the marriage (especially if the couple were both citizens and residents of the same country, that country may want exclusivity on marrying its own citizens).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From Kate's first link:

*International marriage information: Couples from outside the United States can be married in Las Vegas. Most countries will want a certified copy of your marriage certificate and an Apostille from the Nevada Secretary of State. The marriage certificate costs $10 and the Apostille costs $20. The Nevada Secretary of State can send the Apostille and certified marriage certificate copy directly to your government for you.*

Note that this is in addition to the $60 for the marriage license and whatever you pay to whoever actually marries you.  In the US system the government usually doesn't actually perform the marriage, you go to the official of your choice.  Many of the major casinos here have wedding chapels.  You can go to a justice of the peace (low level judge) to get married but I don't think you're going to come halfway around the world for a totally no-frills wedding.  Note that you do pay the justice of the peace if you go that route.