# UK citizen marrying US. citizen in USA under VWP

Tags: visas, usa, uk, us-visa-waiver-program

My fiancee and I are marrying on March 3 in the USA. I'm traveling from Dublin, Ireland to USA.

I am employed in the UK, have authorised leave, return ticket to Ireland and plan to apply for UK spouse visa upon my return. I am traveling from March 1 to March 8 since we are applying for her visa before end of March and I don't want to take too much time off work.

Has anybody any experience in traveling to USA to marry a US citizen then heading back to home country? Unsure what documents to take. I plan on taking my job contract, letter of leave from my manager, last 3 pay slips to prove I'm still employed, return ticket, hotel booking for 1 week in USA, wedding venue booking.

I've been to USA about 6 times over the past 2 years to visit my fiancee. Not sure what questions will be asked, so I plan on arriving about 3 hours before my flight to JFK as not to miss it. Never had too much trouble at the border, when I say I'm visiting my fiancee they just raise an eyebrow, ask what she is employed as, ask what I do back home then usually stamp me through.

Any advice?

Thanks.

Additional info: No, I'm not planning to remain in the USA. Just want to head there, marry my fiancee, then head back.

EDIT: No they do not answer my question, unfortunately. I want to hear from people with experience doing this and what I can expect. I do not know whether to say I am visiting my fiancee or just straight to say I am getting married.

Comment: Also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134190/getting-married-in-the-us-on-a-tourist-visa and probably a bunch more

Comment: As I recall, the rules about notice and residence periods, documentation, blood test requirements, etc. for marriage are state-based, not federal, so you'll need to tell us which state you intend to get married in.